# Entity Framework Core, retrieve data from second level related table with aggregation function

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a situation that I'd like to try that doesn't let me sleep at night. in essence, I would like to display cards (bootstrap type) in a View which, for each person (it's just an example for analogy), show the associated characteristics and the value of the last measurement (for example, imagining that the height was measured at 5 years and then at 10 years ). In a situation similar to that of the image below, it is a best practice to adopt the only logic that I was able to implement (sorry but I am a hobbyist who loves programming, unfortunately I have not studied for that) reported in the code below or Is it better to use Partial View? In the second case, how are they implemented for the second level or better, how is the value of the last date associated with each characteristic?

What I would get: https://codepen.io/lucora/pen/jOKQpGY

[image: Database]

And this is my approach:

**VIEW MODEL**

```
public class ViewModel
{
   public IEnumerable<PersonViewModel>? People { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<FeaturesViewModel>? Features { get; set; }
}

public class PersonViewModel
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name{ get; set; } = string.Empty;
   public string? Surname { get; set; }
   public ICollection<FeaturesViewModel>? FeaturesViewModel{ get; set; }
}

public class FeaturesViewModel
{
   public virtual PersonViewModel? People { get; set; }
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string? Feature{ get; set; } = string.Empty;
   public DateTime? DateLastValue { get; set; } = default;
   public String? StringLastValue { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
var myPeople = _context.Person!.Select(x => new PersonViewModel
{
   Id = (int)x.Id!,
   Name = x.Name,
   Surname = x.Surname
});

var myFeatures = _context.Features!.Select(x => new FeaturesViewModel
{
   Id = x.Id,
   PersonId = (int)x.PersonId!,
   Feature = x.Feature,
   DateLastValue = x.Features.Feature-Value.Max(x => x.DateTimeMeasure), 
   //StringLastValue = ????                 
 });

ViewModel VM = new();
VM.People = myPeople;
VM.Features = myFeatures;

return View(VM);
```

**VIEW**

```
@model VM

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
       <h3>PEOPLE: </h3>
     </div>
</div>
<br />

<div class="row">

    @foreach (var item in Model.People!)
    {
       @*<img src=@item.Logo class="card-img-top" alt="...">*@
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">@item.Surname.ToUpper()</h5>
                <h6 class="card-text mb-2 text-muted">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</h6>
       <hr />
          <p class="card-text">
             FEATURES:
          </p>
       <hr/>
          <p class="card-text">

             @foreach (var feat in Model.Features!.Where(x=>x.PersonId == item.Id))
             {
                 <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                       @feat.Feature - @feat.StringFeatureValue ??
                    </div>
                 </div>
             } //end of Features 
         </p>
      } //end of foreach People
</div>
```

Comment: You want for each person a card with their details and their features ?

Comment: Will be helpful to show the relations of your models

Comment: Hi (ciao) @Darkk L, as mentioned this example is only conceptual to make it clear where I have the problem. Which I failed to represent for my ideal purpose. In any case, I would need for each person on the View to be able to visualize not only the Features (first level of correlation) but also the value of the last one. So for the second level an aggregate function would be needed I think.

Comment: Programming is largely the art of decomposing tasks and then re-composing the components. The main decomposition criterium is "separation of concerns". Applied to your problem: let the UI mind its core task: display data, let the data layer (EF) do its core task: process data. I.e. let EF produce a view model (data ready for display), let the view *just* display it, not bring it all together. So the only focus of this question be: *one* query that only produces `PersonViewModel`s with their `ICollection<FeaturesViewModel>` populated. Then, in another question, ask about displaying it.

Comment: Thank so much #Gert Arnold, I'll do. In my life, I learned only after made a mistake. In this way what learned remain forever with me. Thank you also to @Darkk L.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way:

Your view models

```
public class ViewModel
{
   //the only one list you need in the view
   public IEnumerable<PersonViewModel> People { get; set; }
}

public class PersonViewModel
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name{ get; set; }
   public string Surname { get; set; }
   // All persons features 
   public ICollection<FeaturesViewModel> Features { get; set; }
}

public class FeaturesViewModel
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Feature{ get; set; }
   // last feature value by datetime
   public FeatureValueViewModel LastFeatureValue { get; set; }
}

public class FeatureValueViewModel
{
   public DateTime DateTimeMeassure { get; set; }
   public string MeasureValue { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
//If you have the right relations, You can take all the data you need that way
var people = _context.Person.Select(x => new PersonViewModel
{
   Id = x.Id,
   Name = x.Name,
   Surname = x.Surname
   Features = x.Features.Select(y => new FeaturesViewModel
   {
       Id = y.Id,
       Feature = y.Feature,
       LastFeatureValue = y.FeatureValues.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTimeMeashure).FirstOrDefault(),
   }).ToList();

}).ToList();


ViewModel VM = new();
VM.People = myPeople;

return View(VM);
```

View

```
@model VM

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
       <h3>PEOPLE: </h3>
     </div>
</div>
<br />

<div class="row">

    @foreach (var person in Model.People)
    {
       @*<img src=@item.Logo class="card-img-top" alt="...">*@
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">@item.Surname.ToUpper()</h5>
                <h6 class="card-text mb-2 text-muted">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</h6>
       <hr />
          <p class="card-text">
             FEATURES:
          </p>
       <hr/>
          <p class="card-text">
             //
             @foreach (var feat in person.Features )
             {
                 <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                       @feat.LastFeatureValue.DateTimeMeassure - @feat.LastFeatureValue.MeasureValue
                    </div>
                 </div>
             } //end of Features 
         </p>
      } //end of foreach People
</div>
```